# unable to display image from static folder in node js

Tags: node.js, image, static

New to Node.js and trying to display image from static folder using

`http://localhost:3000/uploads/animal.jpg`

but I cannot display it and receives error `Cannot GET /uploads/C6MGiE-1528523813517.jpg` and when I checked in `uploads` folder. The image was uploaded successfully. Images are being uploaded through `Postman`

> app.ts

```
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import path from "path";
import mediaUploadRoute from "./routes/media-upload.route";

app.use('/api/uploads', mediaUploadRoute);

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const directory: string = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/')
app.use(express.static(directory))
```

> media-upload.route.ts

```
import express from "express";

// mediaFiles is a service that uses multer to host the images to the server
import mediaFiles from "../services/media-files";

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/fileInput_icon', mediaFiles.uploadSingle('fileInput_icon'), (req, res) => {
    let file = req.file;
    file.path = file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/")
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(file.path));
})

router.post('/fileInput_image', mediaFiles.uploadSingle('fileInput_image'), (req, res) => {
    let file = req.file;
    file.path = file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/")
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(file.path));
})

export default router;
```

What would be the reason? I am working on for many days but no success

**Update**

> app.js

```
// it created public folder in the root of project directory
app.use(express.static('/public'));
```

in `multer`

```
private storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: 'public',
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(
                null,
                file.originalname.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })
```

tried to access via

`http://localhost:3000/C6MGiE-1528530542730.jpg`

`http://localhost:3000/public/C6MGiE-1528530542730.jpg`

but all invain :(

`Postman` gets response `"public/C6MGiE-1528530542730.jpg"`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this code:

```
const directory: string = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/')
app.use(express.static(directory))
```

looks in the correct directory, but isn't set up for the right path.  So, when you request `/uploads/C6MGiE-1528523813517.jpg`, it's looking for `__dirname + '/uploads/uploads/C6MGiE-1528523813517.jpg'` which it doesn't find.

You can fix it by changing the requested image URL to just `/C6MGiE-1528523813517.jpg` or by changing the server code to:

```
const directory: string = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');
app.use('/uploads', express.static(directory));
```

Comment: @mwn - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.

Comment: you save my life tnxx